# Linear transformation from $R^3$ to $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How would I solve this question?

Let $T : R^3\rightarrow R^4$ be a linear map, if it is known that $T(2,3,1) =(2,7,6,−7)$, $T (0, 5, 2) = (−3, 14, 7, −21)$, and $T (−2, 1, 1) = (−3, 6, 2, −11)$, find the general formula for $L(x, y, z)$.

I feel like the equation would take the form $T[x,y,z] = [x,y,z,w]$ where the $ w$ can be replaced with some version of the other parts of the vector?

I copied and pasted this from where I saw it. I’m not sure if the ‘$L$’ was intended?

Comment: You know how T acts on 3 linearly independent vectors in R3, so you can express (x, y, z) with these 3 vectors, and find a general formula for how T acts on (x, y, z)

Comment: @numbdigger so is the whole R4 thing a trick when in reality i can solve for a linear combination of the standard basis? Am I not trying to find T?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a trick, just express (x, y, z) as a linear combination of the given vectors and this way you can find T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equations breaking them into basis terms 
Like $2T(e_1) +3T(e_2) +T(e_3) = v_1$

Now solve the matrix equation. You will get images of the standard basis elements.

Now can you complete it?

Note that, it even gives you whether the function is well defined or not.

Comment: Wouldn’t using e1,e2, and e3 get rid of the 4th element in the vectors of T? Since v1 would be a 4x1 then T would have to be a 4x3 since it is multiplied by the 3x1 [x,y,z]. The thing is if I split it up into a linear combination of the column vectors like T_1(x) + T_2(y) + T_3(z) = v1, I don’t see how I would solve it? Like I don’t know how I would set it up with the equations.

Comment: $v_1$ is the row matrix. So, in the right hand side you will get a $3\times 4$ matrix. So multiplying by inverse of the coefficient matrix is legal.

Comment: Hmmmm, how does the left side of the equation result in a row vector? I tried setting up as such                                               [2,3,1,2,7,6,-7]————————————————[0,5,2,-3,14,7,-21]———————————- ————[-2,1,1,-3,6,2,-11]—when I rref the result is this—————-[1, 0, 0, 9/4, -1/4, 3/2, 5/2]——————————————[0, 1, 0,  -2,    1,  -1,  -3]—————————————- [0, 0, 1, 7/2,  9/2,   6,  -3]  when i take the 3x4 part and turn it into a 4x3 the resulting matrix doesn’t work

Comment: I am just writing $v_1= (2,7,6,-7)$ and so on.then the augmented matrix will be $3\times 7$

Comment: i get that since the one i set up was 3x7. I’m confused because multiplying a 4x3 by any e1 on the right or whatever would not result in a row matrix. Did u mean to multiply T on the left by a row e1? Even then I don’t see how a 1x4 row vector could arise. When I set up my augmented matrix did I screw that up or did I screw up my interpretation of the result of the rref?

Comment: Why are considering $4\times 3$ matrix it will be $3\times 4 $ matrix there are 3 equations so three rows.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**Note that $B:=\left\{\, \begin{bmatrix}   2 \\   3 \\1   \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}   0 \\   5 \\2  \end{bmatrix} ,\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\,\right\}$
express vector 
\begin{bmatrix}   x_1 \\   x_2 \\x_3 \end{bmatrix} as a linear combination of the basis vectors in $B$.Namely we find scalar $c_1,c_2,c_3$ satisfying
$\begin{bmatrix}   x_1 \\   x_2 \\x_3 \end{bmatrix}=c_1\begin{bmatrix}   2 \\   3\\1  \end{bmatrix}+c_2\begin{bmatrix}   0\\   5\\2  \end{bmatrix}+c_3\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$
This can be written as the matrix equation
$\begin{bmatrix}   x_1 \\   x_2 \\x_3 \end{bmatrix}=
P\begin{bmatrix}   c_1 \\   c_2  \\c_3\end{bmatrix}$
Where $P=\begin{bmatrix}   2 & 0&-2\\   3& 5&1\\1&2&1 \end{bmatrix}.$
Solve the equation and find the value of the $c_1,c_2,c_3$ . Then use linear transformation. You can easily find the formula for $T$.